# Manage ctrl+z and bg or & signal in shell script - (background process in shell script)

Tags: linux, angular, shell, sh

I have an script that holds inside:

```
cd $1
ng s --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200
...another commands ...
```

so, i want to run an angular project inside that. I'm executting the script from a micro-service so actually that service never gives me back response because of the ng s command's behavior. 
[image]

Keeping that in mind, i want to execute the "ng s ..." command in background, but when i run:

```
ng s --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 &
```

the ng s takes the & as invalid argument. I mean, i tried to run the script in background  several ways with no luck

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

As an option, you can write down a short bash script which contains only

```
#!/bin/bash
ng s --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200
```

and then start it as

`script.sh &`

or if you want to keep it running after disconnecting from the terminal:

`nohup script.sh &`

Comment: I'm already tried that way, and when i run it from the console it works, but when i run from the microservice it sends the & as a parameter to the shell, so it doesn't takes the & as the console does.

Comment: how exactly do you start it as a microservice? is it a docker container?

Comment: @riverfall Oh yeah, it is a docker container. And the microservice is written in java and executes commands.

Comment: @CesarLeonardoOchoaContreras please attach the Dockerfile to the question